# ASP.NET Clear Cache

Tags: asp.net, caching

If you cache pages in a HttpHandler with

```
_context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
_context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(180));
```

is it possible to clear a certain page from the cache?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is it possible to Clear a certain page
>   from the Cache?

Yes:

```
HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem("/pages/default.aspx");
```

You can also use Cache dependencies to remove pages from the Cache:

```
this.Response.AddCacheItemDependency("key");
```

After making that call, if you modify `Cache["key"]`, it will cause the page to be removed from the Cache.

In case it might help, I cover caching in detail in my book: [Ultra-Fast ASP.NET](http://tinyurl.com/89lf5xm).

Comment: I assume this only affects caching on the server side and not client side. If you have set caching on client side for 180 seconds, then removing it from the server cache will not affect the client browser? (I know it's a stupid question but I want to be 100% sure). thx.

Comment: Correct. You can't programmatically remove an object from a client-side or proxy-based cache using server-side code. In addition, removing a page from the cache in one server or AppPool won't remove it from the cache in another server or AppPool.

Answer (score 4):

more simple one...

```
public static void ClearCache()
{
    Cache cache = HttpRuntime.Cache;

    IDictionaryEnumerator dictionaryEnumerators = cache.GetEnumerator();

    foreach (string key in (IEnumerable<string>) dictionaryEnumerators.Key)
    {
        cache.Remove(key);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code will remove all keys from the cache:

```
public void ClearApplicationCache(){
    List<string> keys = new List<string>();
    // retrieve application Cache enumerator
    IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator = Cache.GetEnumerator();
    // copy all keys that currently exist in Cache
    while (enumerator.MoveNext()){
        keys.Add(enumerator.Key.ToString());
    }
    // delete every key from cache
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++) {
        Cache.Remove(keys[i]);
    }
}
```

Modifying the second loop to check the value of the key before removing it should be trivial.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is this the same as you would use HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem("/caching/CacheForever.aspx"); "/caching/CacheForever.aspx" being one of the keys of Cache?

Comment: It is indeed - I honestly cannot think of any advantages my method has over calling HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem(); I just took the snippet from some production code I have here, so I know it works correctly.

Comment: I assume this only affects caching on the server side and not client side?